# Encuentra el mayor y menor de 4 números y enseñe los números que están en medio

Tags: java

tengo un ejercicio en JAVA que me pide:
Realiza el programa que solicite al usuario 4 números enteros y muestre en pantalla los dos números que no son ni el más grande ni el más pequeño.

He estado planteando el ejercicio y no llego a una conclusión buena. El código que tengo hasta ahora sería este:

```
    public class ejercicio_21 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int num = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        int num3 = 0;
        int num4 = 0;
        int mayor = 0;
        int menor = 0;
        
        System.out.println("Dame un número: ");
        num = sn.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Dame un número: ");
        num2 = sn.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Dame un número: ");
        num3 = sn.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Dame un número: ");
        num4 = sn.nextInt();
        
        if(num > num2 && num2 > num3 && num3 > num4) {
            mayor = num;
            menor = num4;
            System.out.println("Los números que están en el medio son: " + num2 + " y " + num3);
        } else if(num > num2 && num2 < num3 && num3 > num4) {
            mayor = num2;
            menor = num4;
            System.out.println("Los números que están en el medio son: " + num2 + " y " + num4);
        } else if(num < num2 && num2 > num3 && num3 < num4) {
            mayor = num2;
            menor = num4;
            System.out.println("Los números que están en el medio son: " + num + " y " + num4);                     
        } else if(num2 > num && num > num3 && num3 > num4) {
            mayor = num2;
            menor = num4;
            System.out.println("Los números que están en el medio son: " + num + " y " + num3);         
        } else if(num3 > num && num > num2 && num2 > num4) {
            mayor = num3;
            menor = num4;
            System.out.println("Los números que están en el medio son: " + num + " y " + num2);         
        } else if(num2 > num && num > num3 && num3 > num4) {
            mayor = num2;
            menor = num4;
            System.out.println("Los números que están en el medio son: " + num2 + " y " + num3);            
        }
    }

}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Te daré una pista, convierte tus números en un array (`int[] nums = new int[4];`), asigna el menor y el mayor al primer numero (`nums[0]`) y a partir de ahí solo tienes que comparar.

Comment: Por ahora no hemos llegado a los arrays y tengo que hacerlo de esta manera.

Comment: Y si cambias tu logica a algo mas simple? que tal si pides el primero y lo guardas como mayor y menor.. luego, pides el segundo, lo comparas con mayor y menor y actualizas el que correponda, y guardas el del medio.... y asi con los otros dos... de esa forma, vas a tener todos ordenados...

Comment: Entonces, hazlo tal como te dijo @gbianchi. Que es exactamente lo que te decía yo, pero sin arrays

Answer (score 1):

Como digo siempre, lo primero es que yo también estoy aprendiendo, así que por descontado este no es el mejor código para hacer las cosas, pero cumple lo que necesitas.
Según el enunciado solo tienes que determinar cuál de ellos es el mínimo, cuál el máximo y, a partir de ahí, imprimir TODOS los números entre mínimo y máximo, no? O de los 4 números que te dan decir cuales dos están en medio? Bueno, yo entiendo el ejercicio como te digo en el primer supuesto, y, aunque este código se puede mejorar, realiza lo que necesitas:

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

public class MayorMenor {
    static int mayor, menor,temp;
    static Scanner entrada= new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Dame el primer numero: ");
        temp=entrada.nextInt();
        mayor=temp;
        menor=temp;
        System.out.println("Segundo numero: ");
        entradaComprobada();
        System.out.println("Tercer numero: ");
        entradaComprobada();
        System.out.println("Cuarto numero: ");
        entradaComprobada();
        for (int i = menor ; i<=mayor;i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
    static void entradaComprobada () {
        temp=entrada.nextInt();
        if (temp<menor) menor=temp;
        if (temp>mayor) mayor=temp;
    }
}
```

Siempre puedes mejorarlo. Puedes coger los números en un bucle, puedes guardar una copia de los números que te den por más que no sea el mayor o el menor, o, bueno, lo que necesites...

Espero que al menos, viendo como este código te saca el mayor y el menor, puedas mejorarlo por tu cuenta.

EDIT: he leido mejor y al parecer tienes que determinar cuál es menor, cual mayor, e imprimir los que no lo sean (es decir, los que están entre menor y mayor de los que te han dado):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MayorMenor {
    static int mayor, menor;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int  num1, num2, num3, num4;
        System.out.println("Dame el primer numero: ");
        num1 = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Segundo numero: ");
        num2 = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Tercer numero: ");
        num3 = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Cuarto numero: ");
        num4 = entrada.nextInt();
        mayor = num1;
        menor = num1;
        comprobar(num2);
        comprobar(num3);
        comprobar(num3);
        System.out.print("De los 4 numeros dados, el " + menor + " es el menor, el " + mayor + " es el mayor. Por lo tanto, los que estan en medio son: ");
        comprobarMedio(num1);
        comprobarMedio(num2);
        comprobarMedio(num3);
        comprobarMedio(num4);

    }
    static void comprobar (int num) {
        if (num < menor) menor = num;
        if (num > mayor) mayor = num;
    }
    static void comprobarMedio ( int num) {
        if (num != menor && num != mayor) System.out.print(num + " ");
    }
}
```

PD: Cuando se trate de determinar mayores y menores, lo primero que tienes que hacer es asignarles un valor de los que te hayan dado, no asignarles 0. Porque si tu haces menor=0, y mis cuatro numeros son 4, 25, 100 y 20, ninguno de estos es menor que 0, con lo que tu menor quedará como 0 en lugar de como 4.

Un saludo, y espero que te sirva!

Comment: deja solo la segunda, que es la que vale ;)

Comment: Efectivamente, cuando busques el menor (o el mayor, en verdad se suele hacer igual) se tiene que asignar como menor y mayor siempre el primer valor, no uno determinado por nosotros (0). Por otro lado, te das cuenta que repites la misma sentencia una y otra vez? `temp=entrada.nextInt();
        if (temp<menor) menor=temp;
        if (temp>mayor) mayor=temp;` Lo suyo sería poner eso en una función y evitas repetir el mismo código una y otra y otra vez

Comment: Se agradecen las correcciones. Voy a hacer modificar lo que comenta Benito (o al menos, como creo que debería de quedar después de su comentario).
Sobre lo que comentas gbianchi, yo es que al leer el enunciado entiendo lo que puse en el primer ejemplo, no crees?

Comment: Editado, espero que estén bien. Muchas gracias.